# what is the meaning of " Axe me No question"

Tags: meaning

I have seen it appeared in a game but not sure the meaning of it. I will appreciate it if someone coul

Comment: What game? Add a screenshot?

Answer (score 4):

From an [article](https://www.npr.org/sections/codeswitch/2013/12/03/248515217/why-chaucer-said-ax-instead-of-ask-and-why-some-still-do?t=1533290210131) about the subject on npr.org:

> The most common stereotype of black vernacular is the pronunciation of
>   the word "ask" as "ax." "Ax" has gotten a bad rap for years.

But,

> Jesse Sheidlower, the president of the American Dialect Society, says
>   "ax" has been used for a thousand years. "It is not a new thing; it is
>   not a mistake," he says. "It is a regular feature of English."
>
> Sheidlower says you can trace "ax" back to the eighth century. The
>   pronunciation derives from the Old English verb "acsian." Chaucer used
>   "ax." It's in the first complete English translation of the Bible (the
>   Coverdale Bible): " 'Axe and it shall be given.'

University linguist John Rickford adds that while there's nothing technically wrong with saying "ax", it's just no longer considered mainstream English.

Comment: I think ax is a common pronunciation in London also.

Comment: Not in any part of London that I grew up in! But I have certainly heard it in Wiltshire.

Answer (score 0):

It means "ask me no question", "do not ask me questions".

That resource is used to reflect some sort of specific accent. It's the word "ask" written how it's supposed to be pronounced by a non native English speaker or by someone from Scottland, Wales or some other place with an special accent.

I don't mean specifically Scottish accent in this case, I mean an special accent. I can not identify all English speaking places that pronounces "/æks/" instead of "/ɑːsk/".

Also it's a pun of words if the character got an actual [axe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/axe) [a tool used for chopping wood, typically of iron with a steel edge and wooden handle]

Comment: Scotland, Wales?? I doubt it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was talking about this KIND of resource not about this SPECIFIC case. I'm no expert in English accents, you are right. Maybe, as stated by Mattias, it just reflects an old-fashioned way of saying "ask"

Answer (score 0):

This is a phenomenon known as *metathesis*, where the order of consonants is switched.  Already in the Old English period, centuries before the Norman Conquest, we find the verbs *ascian* and *acsian*, "to ask". In some modern dialects you hear /æks/ and in standard modern English /æsk/  (the vowel can move more to the front or more to the back).